# RecordNotFound when viewing list of secondary resources in Refinery extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails.  I've got an installation of Refinery CMS in which I've created two extensions that are related.  I pretty much followed [this guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/relating-resources-in-an-extension).  I've got it all working, except that for my second resource (event_types), I'm not able to view them from the front end.  The link to view the Event Types goes to `localhost:3000/events/event_types`, and that makes the `events` viewer think I'm trying to look at an `event` with ID "event_types", and I get a RecordNotFound error.  What is set up wrong?  It seems like it's something wrong with routes, but I don't know what to change.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified so you have to take care about order in `config/routes.rb` file.

For example given in [guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/relating-resources-in-an-extension), in file `vendor/extensions/events/config/routes.rb` you should put `event_type` resource routes **above** `event` resource route.

```
# Frontend routes
namespace :events do
  resources :event_types, :only => [:index, :show]
end

# Frontend routes
namespace :events do
  resources :events, :path => '', :only => [:index, :show]
end
```

To better understand Rails routes you can check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html